# Approach for selecting multiple phone numbers and email address

Tags: iphone, user-interface, abaddressbook, multipleselection

In an iPhone App, I want to add functionality of inviting friends from the Addressbook of iPhone. I have successfully fetched contacts from Addressbook and displayed them in UITableView (using custom UITableViewCell with name, number and email).

Now, for **single** phone number and **single** email address, Every thing is fine. Problem comes when the **multiple** phone number and **multiple** email address are there for a contact (which will be there for most of the time).

The solution I found was giving all there details in the DetailViewContoller (another ViewController for selection only, which makes the process unfriendly to user), and giving choice to user to select numbers and emails as he/she wants.

I would like to know, if anyone has faced the same problem and tried **different approach?**

**Note:** Displaying multiple emails and numbers in same UITableViewCell is not a problem at all. The problem is to find the simplest approach to select multiple values for single user to send invitation. Hope, I am making sense to you. Let me know, if you have any doubts.

Anyone???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope you can have a grouped uitableview inwhich each sections displays a user contact details in different rows..also with a UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark and handle the selection in didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate. Something like a section displays a user details. as each info like number, mail, etc.. are in different rows u can easily handle the selection also.